# Is providing an answer on previously self-solved questions incorrect?

Tags: support

I [added an answer](https://superuser.com/a/1477392/912095) to a question that was some time ago resolved in the comments only, as it just got another low-quality answer, and to have it resolved.

It seems that was not the correct thing to do, but, being new, I don't have any reference and I couldn't find any hint how to handle the case in the Help center.

Should I instead have flagged the question, vote to close it perhaps?
Is the question useless or invalid after the Op solved it through the comments?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer looks perfectly fine. We do *really* prefer to have answers over comments, and on its own, it gives all the information that anyone needs.

On the whole? Looks good.

Comment: Would it be considered _nicer_ to mark the answer Community wiki in that case, so it doesn't look like reputation hunting? I can only guess that's what the downvotes came for.

Comment: No need to. That is not what community wikis are for - and honestly I *personally* feel that community wikis are a legacy feature that we typically ought not to be using